# URL Beautification using .htaccess or php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In search of a more userfriendly & search engine friendly urls, i want have beautied my urls:
The htacces apache rule that achieves this (Thanks to Laurence Gonsalves)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*) /$2?ln=$1 [L]
```

which makes this possible:
`/uk/somepage`  instead of   `/somepage?ln=uk`
`/de/somepage`  instead of   `/somepage?ln=de`
`/ja/somepage`  instead of   `/somepage?ln=ja`

**Now the difficult part:** previously, the url was replaced with a normal link like `href="?ln=de"` or `href="?ln=it"` for changing language of the current page. But now how can i achieve that? Sothat the current page stays the same, but only the preceding two lowercase letters that say to the browser what language it is in change?

So how to tell the link to only change the `/uk/contact` to `/de/contact` once the german (de) language flag is clicked? php solution to rewrite the url or htaccess solutions are accepted.

I found out that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will output `/uk/somepage` but i cant write the php code that can split up the components, add a new language code like "de" into it, which i can put manually into a normal href that goes on a German flag. etc. Thanks for any and all clues/answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to look at something like [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) to strip out the non-language part of the URL (e.g., /contact) and just add it again to a new string containing the language identifier.

Maybe this could get you started:

```
<?php

function changeLanguageLink($language_id)
{
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $link = preg_replace('/\/?(uk|de)\/(.*)/', "/$2", $uri);    
    $link = $language_id . $link;

    return $link;
}

?>

<a href="changeLanguage('uk');">Change language to UK</a>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Sheldon! will check your solution out now!

Comment: :( Gives an error saying page doesnt exist. With the limited logical mind i have, is it possible that the "changeLanguage('uk');" should be "setLanguageLink('uk');" but even then it doesnt work:  [error] File does not exist:

Comment: I think this is the elegant answer, if only it worked. i have hopes!

Comment: im on to something! had to replace it with <a href="<? echo setLanguageLink('de'); ?>">Change language to UK</a> It does remove the page but not the language, and adds both new language and page:
seems solved if i add a /  in fromt of the url:  <a href="/<? echo 
/nl/de/testing

Comment: It works It Works It Works jiupppieieee Thanks so much Sheldon! Long live opensource communities!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can split the request_uri using, well, [split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) or [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$uri_bits=explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

In theory the language identifier will be in $uri_bits[ 1] (as [0] would contain a zero length string, but you should test it by print_r()-ing the array). Of course, you should test if the $uri_bits[ 1] exists, and it's the language identifier, the simplest way to do it would be:

```
if($uri_bits[1]==$_GET['lang'])
```

Then you can change that and concatenate the bits again using [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$uri_bits[1]="it";
$url_german=implode('/', $uri_bits);
```

At least that's how I'd do it.